# Rails assets:precompile:all works for root user but not normal user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a RoR project that is built through Bamboo, but hasn't been built for over a year.
All developers connected to the project have moved on, and little rails knowledge is left in the company.

I have been trying to make a minor change, but the build is failing during the asset compile stage:

```
/usr/bin/env  ruby -S rake assets:precompile
/var/bamboo/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7/bin/jruby /var/bamboo/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.6.7/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
undefined method `each_logical_path' for nil:NilClass
```

While trying to debug this, I have gone on the build agent and run the command manually.

If I run it as the root user, it succeeds, if I run it as the bamboo user, it fails as above.

I dug further, adding a few 'puts' here and there, and found the reason a nil object is getting to that point.

There is an assets.rake file with the following:

```
env      = Rails.application.assets
```

*env* is eventually passed to the failing code above.

When run as root, *env* has a class type of *Sprockets::Index*, but when run as the normal user (bamboo) it is nil.

I have compared environment variables of the two users (such as the PATH), and I couldn't find any differences that I could attribute to this, but my experience with rails is minimal, so I might have missed something.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, or even offer hints on how I can better debug this problem?

Comment: Is this hosted on Heroku?

Comment: No, it is hosted on our own servers. I think the box is Centos (El5 or 6, not sure).

Comment: You might want to consider getting a local dev environment set up to experiment on. Trying to do stuff like this from the production server can be tough. Trying something like "RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile" Do some google searches on compiling assets in production.

Comment: I'm not doing it in prod (good way to lose your job!), but a bamboo build machine.
I have been trying to get a local env running, but I'm coming across unrelated issues: https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/562

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved this issue.

A recent change moved the production logging location from /tmp/app.log to /var/log/app_logs/app.log

It seems the RoR build / asset compile stage uses the production log location, which didn't exist on the build machine, and the bamboo user didn't have write access either.

In the end I added an additional step to the bamboo plan to create the directory & file and to set r/w permissions on the log.